# Hyperledger fabric: No script

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am following the tutorial on http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io to setup my own hyperledger. I am building the first network using "first-network" in the fabric-samples. The ./byfn -m generate is OK, but after using ./byfn -m up I receive the below error:

```
/bin/bash: ./scripts/script.sh: No such file or directory
```

The script.sh file is available in:

```
\fabric-samples\first-network\scripts
```

After running 'docker ps -a' I get:
[image]

My OS is Windows 10. Does anyone know what is causing this and how to resolve this?

Comment: Is this resolved? I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html#windows-extras  - specifically this part on Git settings required for Windows prior to cloning the samples repository:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

Comment: Facing same issue even after performing all windows-extra commands on windows 10

Comment: Did you enable these settings and then clone the repository?  If you did not have these settings enabled, you'll need to delete your local clone, enable these settings and then clone the repo again.  What terminal are you using?   I use Git Bash on Windows 10.

Comment: I removed last cloned instance and re-excuted the commands. I am using docker quickstart terminal.