# Hyperledger Fabric My first network

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to work on my first network in Hyperledger Fabric. Using the following documentation http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

I have completed the setup till http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#create-join-channel but when I run the

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I got hte following error:

> Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST

In attempt to resolve i follow the solution given at [First network in hyperledger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434262/first-network-in-hyperledger/46874545?noredirect=1#comment80696424_46874545) but faced error on running

```
/bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
```

I brought my network down using

```
./bfyn.sh -m down
```

and bring the network up that gave me following error:

> ERROR: for orderer.example.com  Cannot start service orderer.example.com: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "process_
>   linux.go:368: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\"/c/Users/lenovo/fabric-samples/first-network/channel-artifacts/genesis.block\\" to rootfs \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/16c8954b277dec9a00370bdaa4316db282759b3dd6892ffc25f860a4c9e06d58\\" at\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/16c8954b277dec9a00370bdaa4316db282759b3dd6892ffc25f860a4c9e06d58/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"":Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
>   ERROR !!!! Unable to start network
>   Error response from daemon: No such container: cli

Comment: Also my OS is windows

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779061/hyperledger-fabric-no-script

Comment: @christo4ferris i did check that question and it has no solution in it even i had followed Windows Extra completely and my git config variable are set as mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Delete as admin the channel-artifacts folder, down the network and restart it. Your error must be related to an error at channel-artifacts generation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in /c/users when you run the curl command, as documented [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

Continue on with other setup instructions

also, please make sure you run your docker command prompt in administrator mode.